# Scheduling Jobs one after other in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, job-scheduling

I have written an script `After.sh` to postpone one job to be started after another running job is finished:

```
echo "Waiting job $1 to be finished..."
while ps -p $1 >/dev/null; do sleep 1; done ;
echo "Job $1 finished."
echo "Now running job ${*:2}..."
${*:2}
echo "Job ${*:2} finished."
```

I run it like `After.sh 5327 shutdown 0` to shutdown the PC after the job with PID=5327 is finished. Even I can run it like `After.sh "5327 5778 5935" shutdown 0`, this way it waits until all jobs 5327 5778 and 5935 are finished first.

My problem is when I want to feed a more complex job as argument to the script, for instance:

```
After.sh 5327 for f in *; do echo $f; done
```

Now it runs with an error: `for: command not found`. I tried to replace the command `${*:2}` in the script to `sh ${*:2}` or `eval ${*:2}`, but they failed (`sh` fails again to find `for` command, `eval` keeps the first value of `$f` for the whole loop, so prints the name of the first file every time.)

Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Save the complex command to a file, make it executable, give the path to it as the argument to After.sh.

Comment: @choroba Thanks, I am aware about it, but I like my script to be flexible enough for just in time piece of shell commands, because every time I need different commands

Comment: You will have to dive deep into quotting and backslashing. Cannot you use `wait` instead?

Comment: @choroba Do you believe `wait` would be a simpler solution for my purpose?

Comment: `wait PID ; for f in * ; do echo $f; done` works. It does not take several arguments, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is, that you are `for f in *; do echo $f; done` is not a *command*, but rather it is *bash*-code, which needs a bash-interpreter to be executed.

you can start an interpreter by using `eval`:

```
#!/bin/sh

PID="$1"
shift
JOB="$@"

echo "Waiting job ${PID} to be finished..."
while ps -p ${PID} >/dev/null; do sleep 1; done ;
echo "Job ${PID} finished."
echo "Now running job '${JOB}'"
eval ${JOB}
echo "Job '${JOB}' finished."
```

then use single quotes for commands including variables that should be evaluated by `After`:

```
./After.sh 123 'for f in *; do echo $f; done'
```